# Can't create table in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm new to hbase. I installed hbase on my linux without installing hadoop/hdfs. It's a standalone hbase instance running against local file system. I then started hbase using bin/start-hbase.sh, and could see the org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster process running using ps -ef. However, when I use jps | grep HMaster, there was no output. I then used ./bin/hbase shell and tried to create a table, and it gave me the following error message:

ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: `HBase` requires a working `Zookeeper`. Check out [Section 2.2.1](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/standalone_dist.html) of HBase documentation.

Comment: I ran my hbase in standalone mode, and in standalone mode, HBase does not use HDFS -- it uses the local filesystem instead -- and it runs all HBase daemons and a local ZooKeeper all up in the same JVM, according to Section 2.2.1 of HBase documentation.

Comment: Hence the need to run Zookeeper. Let me paraphrase what you just wrote _it uses the local filesystem instead -- and it runs all HBase daemons and a local __ZooKeeper__ all up in the same JVM_.

Comment: I used the bin/start-hbase.sh command to bring up hbase, and I thought the local ZooKeeper was brought up in the same HMaster process. Maybe I am wrong. How could I run the ZooKeeper process? With what command?

Comment: As user `hbase` run `hbase zkcli` or `zookeeper-client`. Within `zk client` run `ls /`. If you get a list then `zookeeper` is up and running. You just need to update hbase configuration to point to correct zk path. `HBase` on startup will create this zk node. Check your hbase log.

Comment: Try to post your `hbase` configuration as well.

Comment: I changed the hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort property to 2182 in the hbase-site.xml file because 2181 was taken by another process. Could this be the reason?

Comment: That is definitely the reason if you didn't update the `zookeeper` configuration to listen on port `2182`.

Comment: I just ran hbase zkcli and within it I ran ls / , "[hbase, zookeeper]" is what I got.

Comment: That proves `zookeeper` is up and running and `hbase` registers its service. `ls /hbase` will show you more information and keep digging until you see all the necessary information. Verify that what `zookeeper` have is consistent with your hbase configuration.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if you are using hostnames in your configuration, make sure they are in `/etc/hosts` or name resolution will fail unless you have your own `dns` server.

Comment: can u check if there is a zookeeper daemon running? Also, please check your Hbase logs and post the contents.